# Syntax error in conditional expression

Tags: linux, shell, while-loop

I try:

```
        while [[ $c -le $n]]
        do
        now=$(date +"%T")
        echo "Tps at :- $now"
        @c=$c+1
        done
```

I got:

```
   syntax error in conditional expression

   syntax error near `do'
```

Can someone figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a space before closing test expression

```
while [[ $c -le $n ]]
```

And surround your variable with "" to avoid some painful error :

```
while [[ "$c" -le "$n" ]]
```